# How to get content from response in grails 2.4.4

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Recently we were upgrading our application from grails version 2.2.4 to 2.4.4. But we got stuck in one specific problem related to sitemesh filter which was removed from web.xml from grails version 2.4.4.

The problem is, in our code base(grails version 2.2.4) the **response** object was being initialized at **runtime** by **org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsContentBufferingResponse**(http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/sitemesh/GrailsContentBufferingResponse.html) and we used **response.response.contents** to get the html contents of the rendered gsp page and then used it for pdf rendering in the application filter of our application.

```
pdfRenderer(uri: '/pdf/**') {
            afterView = {
                byte[] pdf = PdfUtils.makePdf(response.response.contents, params.title, params.avoidDefaultHeader ?: false, session.user, servletContext)
```

As from grails version 2.4.4 sitemesh filter has replaced with **GrailsLayoutView** the response object is now initialized with **weblogic httpServletResponse** which have no method to get the content.Now we must configure the application to use **GrailsContentBufferingResponse**  at runtime so that the response object get initialized with it.

This is why our application has been broke down, in case of all pdf rendering.

Can anyone please tell me how to configure GrailsLayoutView so that the response object get initialized with  GrailsContentBufferingResponse object at runtime. Or is there any other way to use the sitemesh filter so that the application use GrailsContentBufferingResponse object at runtime.

**I have also created a jira issue at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11896 . Please visit and vote if this is really a bug in grails 2.4.4**